# If two or more DIVs are populated how do I show a third?

Tags: jquery, html, function

I'm trying to write a function in Javascript (mainly jQuery) that displays a DIV when a number of DIVs are populated with content, for example,

If DIVs 1 and 2 are populated with content, say two books for a list, then DIV three appears allowing them to submit that content.

Has anyone come across this before, or have any ideas how I can get jQuery to do this, as I need both DIVs to be populated before any type of submission data is available.

I've managed to set up a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/takuhii/xmnMG/3/

```
ALL CODE ON JSFIDDLE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** - How I did it:

Basically, I set this in my each of my functions

```
$("#myID1").attr('rel', 'done');
$("#myID2").attr('rel', 'done');
$("#myID3").attr('rel', 'done');
```

so they now look like this:

```
$('#flyout1 .subProd').click(function() {
    var id1 = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#partnum1").val(id1);  
    $("#myID1").html($("#" + $(this).attr('id')).html());
    $("#myID1").css("border", "none");
    $("#mainID1 #close").css("display", "block");
    $("#mainID1 .button, #mainID1 .qv").css("display", "none");
    $("#myID1").attr('rel', 'done'); /* ADD REL=DONE to DIV */
});
```

then ran this to check for `REL=DONE`

```
setInterval(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var Prod1 = $("#myID1").attr("rel");
    if (Prod1 == "done") {
        count += 1;
    }
    var Prod2 = $("#myID2").attr("rel");
    if (Prod2 == "done") {
        count += 1;
    }
    var Prod3 = $("#myID3").attr("rel");
    if (Prod3 == "done") {
        count += 1;
    }

    if (count == 3) {
        $('#prodSubmit').show()
    } else {
        $('#prodSubmit').hide();
    }
}, 300);
```

On each of my remove functions I added:

```
$("#myID1").removeAttr("rel")
$("#myID2").removeAttr("rel")
$("#myID3").removeAttr("rel")
```

Because the counter only adds one if `REL=DONE`, it automatically "subtracts" ONE if a REL is missing, therefore my counter can only ever achieve a maximum of three, in this case. As you can see from the end of the `setInterval` statement, when `count=3` it shows the DIV the user needs to submit there information. hope this proves useful to someone else too :)

Comment: Please share the code that you already have, preferrably via jsFiddle. You'll get more answers and their quality will be higher. Also, don't forget to format your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by various easier methods. Depends upon how exactly you're populating divs? Otherwise as per your exact question you can do this.

```
$(function(){
if ($.trim($('#Prod1').text()!='' && $.trim($('#Prod2').text()!='' &&  $.trim($('#Prod3').text()!='')))) {
    $('#prodSubmit').show();
}
```

})

Comment: I am populating the DIVs via .HTML() It's copying DIVs from further down the page into the list for submission ;)

Comment: @takuhii That's why showing your code is important. Otherwise people have to guess at what you're doing

Comment: is there an event you can bind to? if not use `setInterval` method to run the code by @tomados.

Comment: I've supplied a FIDDLE in the OP, sorry for the ambiguity, I need to keep this one quite close to my chest for now, this is the last piece I am struggling with :/

Comment: The code above shows a SUBMIT option regardless of whether the DIVS are filled in or not :/

Comment: Hi @takuhii.. I updated the code in the fiddle and above answer. Try this.

Comment: Thanks :) Is that http://jsfiddle.net/xmnMG/7/ As JSFiddle is incrementing the URL everytime we amend it?

Comment: I eventually solved this by assigning a REL attribute of DONE to the required DIVs and counting the number of REL attributes on the page (using setInterval), when the count reaches three it shows the hidden DIV I need to submit the details. it also removed the REL of DONE when you remove details from a particular DIV